# How to use \n in regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

The initial String is

```
System.out.println(myString)
```

looks like this

```
Name: Sacha
Last name: Sidor
.............
Name: Masha
........
```

---

I am trying to capture the second name, i.e. Masha

```
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Name:.*?){2}\\n");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
            String secondName = "";
            while (matcher.find()) {
            secondName = matcher.group();
              }
            System.out.println(secondName); // prints nothing ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to make `.` match all characters including newline. Without `DOTALL` flag, `.` does not match newline.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Name:.*?)(?:Name: )([^\\n]+)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
String secondName = "";
if (matcher.find())
    secondName = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(secondName);
```